# How to do a Key Value pair in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Array `X = [1,3,5]` and `Y = ["X", "Y", "Z"]`.
I need to generate output that looks like this `{1:X}, {3:Y}, {5:Z}`

I try this code

```
var X = [1,3,5];
var Y = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

var myArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        myArray.push({ i : Y[i] });
    };
```

But that code generates a Y array without X array
What jQuery code should I do to make it work?

Comment: `i:` should be `[i]:` to evaluate `i` as a variable.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery question, and merging arrays is well covered here.